# how to i make a barrier where text cannot pass, Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a long label but i don't know how to create a barrier around the window where when the label reaches the end it auto starts a new line, i don't know what to do?

Comment: Try `textwrap.fill(...)` from `textwrap` module.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, you can use tkinter.Text to auto start new lines. Since tkinter.Text is editable by the user, you have to disable with the the option state:

```
import tkinter
win=tkinter.Tk()
long_label=tkinter.Text(win, height=2, width=5)
long_label.pack()
long_label.insert(INSERT, "This is a very long text.")
long_label.config(state="disabled")
```